# How to install chrome when behind a proxy?

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome, download, installation, proxy

Here at college, I am behind a proxy.

To install chrome, I download **ChromeSetup.exe** file and run it.
Now it needs to connect to the internet in order to download the actual software. But I am behind a proxy. The **ChromeSetup.exe** file that I just executed does not detect/ask the proxy and tries to connect to the internet and fails.

I can't find a fix.
Any ideas what might be done??

[This problem is **not** about setting the proxy when the browser is installed. Its about **downloading** and **installing** the browser.]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to download the Offline installer from [here](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1). For some reason it seems that Google don't expose the ?standalone=1 version of the download link on their own pages.

**EDIT**: Alternatively you could try [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Google-Chrome-Download-108166.html). It has a mirror link for each of the different versions you might want.

Comment: you are right, i could not find the standalone installer, and the link below has some issue, so i do not have the chrome browser still :(

Comment: I was just able to download the installer using that link, perhaps its an issue with your proxy?

Comment: dont know... everything else is downloading fine...
lemme c
thanks

Comment: i have downloaded the dev version in the Softpedia link. This one downloaded fine :)

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 2):

A standalone setup is available at [this location](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1). This is the full version, not an installer that will download the rest.

Comment: are you sure this is a working link? I am getting "Connection timed out!"

Comment: Worked fine for me when I posted my message. The EXE is still on my HD.

Comment: okay...
i dont know why this is happening.
i tried thrice

everything else is downloading fine. What can be the problem??

Thanks anyways.

Comment: 5 years later it appears to download an installer to download the rest.

Answer (score 0):

the blessings of Filehippo.com, full installers only :)

[Google Chrome](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/)